# rails correct user method for editing, undefined method 'find'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got an app where users can add an organisation to their account. I want them to be able to edit their organization, and protect it from being edited by any other user. it looks like this

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  private

  def correct_user
    @organization = current_user.organization.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @organization.nil?
  end
end
```

models

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :organization
end
```

Through Rspec I can find a record for current_user.organization. However when i call current_user.organization.find_by I receive a undefined method 'find_by'.

Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `organization` is a single record, it will not respond to `find_by`.

Also, you're checking if `organization` is `nil` after calling a method on it. At this time it is too late. If it is `nil`, and you try to call `find_by` on it, you'll get a `NoMethodError`.

Instead try this:

```
def correct_user
  if current_user.organization && current_user.organization.id == params[:id].to_i
    @organization = current_user.organization
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to work, but for some reason my `params[:id]` is a string and my `current_user.organization.id` is an int. so it works if I use  `current_user.organization && current_user.organization.id == params[:id].to_f` any idea why?

Comment: just found out that if `current_user.organization = nil' calling `.id` raises another error

Comment: @Mischa: Right. You're correct. Comparison in Ruby is type sensitive. If it is `nil`, however, evaluation will never get past the first `current_user.organization` check.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the relation between Organization and User is one-to-one, you don't need to call `find`. `@organization = current_user.organization` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my answer before. I have revised into this.

```
def correct_user
  @organization = Organization.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if current_user.id != @organization.user_id
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

When current user is not owner of organization will be redirected to root_url.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my answer to validate organization by owner only.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient  way to handle this is to implement the correct_user method in the Organization controller as follows.

```
 # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
```

**Debug helper**

Add this in your controller to see the contents of the hash at run time

```
flash[:info] = "Hash: #{params}"
```